# Is there a way to evaluate a function as the input to a match arm?

Tags: function, rust, pattern-matching, match

```
match input_string {
    func_that_returns_string(MyEnum::MyVariant1) => do_something(),
    func_that_returns_string(MyEnum::MyVariant2) => do_something_else(),
    _=> do_nothing(),
}
```

Here is an examples of the error message:
Error: expected tuple struct or tuple variant, found function `func_that_returns_string`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The intended behavior is unclear.

Comment: If the strings you want to match correspond to enum variants, you may want to implement `FromStr for MyEnum`. You can then use `match input_string.parse::<MyEnum>()` with arms like `Ok(MyEnum::MyVariant1)` or `Err(_)`.

Comment: `match` arms have to be patterns, which are more or less literal-ish values you can extract data from by pattern matching. An `if-else` would be better suited for what you're doing, although what it looks like you're actually trying to do is map strings to `MyEnum` variants? In which case you probably want the inverse of `func_that_returns_string`.

Answer (score 7):

Well, you can do it using a [match guard](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-03-pattern-syntax.html#extra-conditionals-with-match-guards), which looks like `x if condition =>`

```
fn fun(variant: MyEnum) -> String {
    match variant {
        MyEnum::Variant1 => "String1".to_string(),
        MyEnum::Variant2 => "String2".to_string(),
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let s = "String2".to_string();
    match s {
        s if s == fun(MyEnum::Variant1) => do_something(1),
        s if s == fun(MyEnum::Variant2) => do_something(2),
        _ => {},
    }

    // prints 2
}
```

But either way it looks clumsy and I suggest you to revise your design.

Comment: Yeah it is clumsy.... Too bad. Seems a little counterintuitive that my code above doesn't work.

Comment: I suppose match expressions are compiled with little overhead, because they're static. While using results of arbitrary functions cannot be optimized, as well as the match guard

Comment: The part before the arrow in each match arm is a _pattern_, not an expression. A function call doesn't make much sense in a pattern – it's not really a pattern you can match against.

Comment: if you ask me match guard are useless and make code hard to read and more long to write

Comment: Match guards have their uses, but this isn't one of them.